# AppMaker strips CSS variables

Tags: google-app-maker

Is it possible to utilise CSS variables within Google App Maker?

```
:root {
  --pale-grfn-grey: #e0dcd5;
}

.app-header-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom-color: var(--pale-grfn-grey);
}
```

The deployed or previewed app doesn't include either the definition or the `border-bottom-color` call.

I maintain an external CSS which we use for other websites and apps, is the best recourse to use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually App Maker doesn't strip CSS variables. The cause of the problem is that App Maker prefixes [Global Styles](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/styles) with `#app`, what breaks your initial variables setup.

```css
/* Design time Global CSS */
:root {
  --customColor: red;
}

.app-MyPage-MyPage {
  background-color: var(--customColor);
}


/* Runtime time Global CSS */
#app :root {
  --customColor: red;
}

#app .app-MyPage-MyPage {
  background-color: var(--customColor);
}
```

There is an easy way to cheat App Maker to make variables work:

```css
/* Design time Global CSS
   NOTE: there is no :root in the beginning BUT
   there is a whitespace OR new line */
 {
  --customColor: red;
}

.app-MyPage-MyPage {
  background-color: var(--customColor);
}

/* Runtime time Global CSS */
#app {
  --customColor: red;
}

#app .app-MyPage-MyPage {
  background-color: var(--customColor);
}
```

It will work but there is no guarantee that App Maker will close this door in the future (or fix the original issue).

I would also consider moving all variables into CSS file and adding it as external CSS resource (I'm not sure if editor will pick up it in design time).

And for sure feel free to file a bug to App Maker team: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410